# Ignore Files In Repo When Deploying To Netlify

Tags: github, netlify

I have a Github repo that includes some large graphical assets. These assets result in failed deploys to Netlify due to Netlify's size restrictions. Is there any way I can keep these files within the Github repo but exclude them from Netlify deploys, in the same way I could use a [.slugignore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore) file when deploying to heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netlify doesn't really have explicit size restrictions, though uploads of files >20MB may fail.  Are your files bigger than that?  If so, hosting them on Netlify's CDN also doesn't make sense as the CDN edge cache will ignore them and they'll load slowly for browsers anyway.

To not deploy them, the most straightforward way is to remove them after your build, something like this:

`npm run build && rm dist/hugefile1.jpg dist/subdir/hugefile2.pdf`

You can get fancier and use a file to list them or just look for everything huge.  Warning - something huge that it DOES make sense to host is your sourcemap (if you use one), so watch out for what this might catch!

`npm run build && find dist -type f -size +20M`

Effectively - you can do anything you could do in a shell script. NB: **You need to make sure that your build pipeline fails if any necessary step fails** - this is why the examples show `&&` to chain commands rather than `;` (build could fail, find succeed, and we publish an empty site!).

More details here:  https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/ and you can test out your scripts using the methodology described here: https://github.com/netlify/build-image#testing-locally